# bootstrapping angular (2.x +) to other platforms

Tags: angular

Angular docs mention that

> Angular offers a variety of bootstrapping options targeting multiple
>   platforms

They then proceed to bootstrapping to the browser using *`platformBrowserDynamic`*.

My question is what other platforms can an angular app be built for?

Some examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular can be used also to develop:

- Mobile apps using Ionic Framework (https://ionicframework.com)
- Desktop apps using Electron (https://electronjs.org)